# How does the Ring of the Darkhidden interact with spells/effects that detect/reveal/dispell invisibility?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

The **Ring of the Darkhidden** is found in the *Magic Item Compendium* page 122 and says:

> You are invisible to darkvision, although you are fully visible in
> normal light.

How do spells such as **See Invisibility**, **Invisibility Purge**, **True Seeing**, or other such spells/abilities interact with the ring's effect?  I'm assuming **True Seeing** works since it trumps everything illusion, but what about the others? **Invisibility** works on both vision and darkvision, so is the ring's effect simply discount invisibility or would it count as a different enough effect to bypass spells that only trip on "invisibility"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Invisibility is a specific status condition](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#invisibility), and *ring of the darkhidden* grants it in a limited form. This is completely reasonable with respect to the definition of invisibility, which defines itself as

> Visually undetectable.

and goes on to describe several different types of senses that can detect invisible creatures where “normal vision” cannot. *Ring of the darkhidden* simply makes you “visually undetectable” with all that entails to those relying on darkvision, but *not* to normal vision. It’s still the invisibility condition, and thus *see invisibility* would thwart it.

Note, however, that (as far as I know), no creature with darkvision lacks normal vision. Thus, *ring of the darkhidden* is only useful in situations where you cannot be seen by normal vision to begin with—i.e. it’s so dark only darkvision works. With *ring of the darkhidden*, it doesn’t.