# Does attacking cause the Ring of the Darkhidden's effect to break?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

The **Ring of the Darkhidden** is found in the *Magic Item Compendium* page 122 and says:

> You are invisible to darkvision, although you are fully visible in
> normal light.

Since the results of my previous question regarding is the effect of the **Ring of the Darkhidden** invisibility (located [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/198202/how-does-the-ring-of-the-darkhidden-interact-with-spells-effects-that-detect-rev)) determined that yes it is, does attacking cause the effect to break the way it does with **Invisibility**?  The description doesn't specify and referring to the spell doesn't help since it does break with **Invisibility** but doesn't with **Greater Invisibility**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Attacking with an active Ring of the Darkhidden does not break the limited invisibility it grants.

Nothing in the ring's description says that attacking breaks the limited invisibility it grants. Importantly, it does not include the phrase "as the spell" (thanks [@fectin](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/25662/fectin) for mentioning that) common to a *lot* of "spell in a can" magic items - notably including the [Ring of Invisibility](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/rings.htm#invisibility), which the wearer can activate to "benefit from invisibility, as the spell".

The ["invisible" status](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#invisibility) assumes that attacking does *not* break invisibility:

> If an invisible creature strikes a character, the character struck still knows the location of the creature that struck him (until, of course, the invisible creature moves). The only exception is if the invisible creature has a reach greater than 5 feet. In this case, the struck character knows the general location of the creature but has not pinpointed the exact location.

The spell *[invisibility](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/invisibility.htm)* explicitly ends if the creature it renders invisible attacks, further cementing that "attacks while invisible end invisibility" is a specific "feature" of that spell, rather than of invisibility generally.

Since "attacking breaks invisibility" is a feature of the spell *invisibility* (and a [few](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/invisibilitySphere.htm) [others](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/invisibilityMass.htm) that are "*invisibility*, but..."), there's no particular reason to believe that attacking while wearing the Ring would render the wearer visible to darkvision.

"But", you say, "the item is based on the spell *invisibility*! Surely that means that attacking ends invisibility." The requirements on magic items serve a couple of purposes (eg., gating who can make the item - a Ring of the Darkhidden requires *invisibility*, which is an arcane spell; clerics would have a hard time making such a ring). However, the effects of the spell and the effects of the item aren't firmly linked - see the Ring of Communication (also on p122 of the Magic Item Compendium), which requires [*detect thoughts*](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/detectThoughts.htm), but grants that:

> When you activate a ring of communication, for the next minute you can clearly hear any words spoken by anyone within 1 mile who is wearing another *ring of communication* to which you are attuned.

The Ring of Communication does *not* grant telepathy of any sort, instead relying on spoken words, even though the base spell is *detect thoughts* - one of the earlier telepathy spells.